# Calling python and c++ scripts from android

Tags: java, android, python, android-ndk, sl4a

Hi I'm trying to develop an android application which should use java and python scripts.

I have to send some data to a c++ functions, collect the return data, send this data to python script and finally display the output in android application.

I know we can use android-ndk to use native language functions and android-sl4a to use python functions, but I just want to know what is the best way to combine these two? Is there a better way to do it?

Also, if I use sl4a, does the user's device need to have python installed?

Please help.